# Different behaviour of ctypes c_char_p?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ctypes

I am confused with this behaviour of different versions of python and dont understand why ?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c="hello"
>>> a=ctypes.c_char_p(c)
>>> print(a.value) 
hello

Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 11 2014, 15:08:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c="hello" 
>>> a=ctypes.c_char_p(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

One works while the other gives me an error. Which one is correct ?

If both of them are correct, how can i achieve the same behaviour as 2.7 in 3.3.5 ? I want to pass the char pointer to C from python.

Comment: In Python 3 use `bytes`, i.e. `c = b"hello"`. The `c_char_p` instance points at the private buffer of the `bytes` object, so only use this for `const` parameters that won't modify the string.

Comment: @eryksun If you could add that as an answer with reason of why it changed in python3, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`c_char_p` is a subclass of `_SimpleCData`, with `_type_ == 'z'`. The `__init__` method calls the type's `setfunc`, which for simple type `'z'` is `z_set`.

In Python 2, the [`z_set` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f89216059edf/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1333) (2.7.7) is written to handle both `str` and `unicode` strings. Prior to Python 3, `str` is an 8-bit string. CPython 2.x `str` internally uses a C null-terminated string (i.e. an array of bytes terminated by `\0`), for which `z_set` can call [`PyString_AS_STRING`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#PyString_AS_STRING) (i.e. get a pointer to the internal buffer of the `str` object). A `unicode` string needs to first be encoded to a byte string. `z_set` handles this encoding automatically and keeps a reference to the encoded string in the `_objects`  attribute.

```
>>> c = u'spam'
>>> a = c_char_p(c)
>>> a._objects
'spam'
>>> type(a._objects)
<type 'str'>
```

On Windows, the default ctypes string encoding is `'mbcs'`, with error handling set to `'ignore'`. On all other platforms the default encoding is `'ascii'`, with `'strict'` error handling. To modify the default, call [`ctypes.set_conversion_mode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.set_conversion_mode). For example, `set_conversion_mode('utf-8', 'strict')`.

In Python 3, the [`z_set` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c0e311e010fc/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1326) (3.4.1) does not automatically convert `str` (now Unicode) to `bytes`. The paradigm shifted in Python 3 to strictly divide character strings from binary data. The ctypes default conversions were removed, as was the function `set_conversion_mode`. You have to pass `c_char_p` a `bytes` object (e.g. `b'spam'` or `'spam'.encode('utf-8')`). In CPython 3.x, `z_set` calls the C-API function [`PyBytes_AsString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_AsString) to get a pointer to the internal buffer of the `bytes` object.

Note that if the C function modifies the string, then you need to instead use [`create_string_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) to create a `c_char` array. Look for a parameter to be typed as `const` to know that it's safe to use `c_char_p`.

Comment: In summary, call `ctypes.c_char_p(my_string.encode('utf-8'))` to get it to work in Python 3.x.