# Python ctypes Example Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm working on how to pass a structure with a string field to C via ctypes. I am using Python3 on Ubuntu (DigitalOcean). I've been struggling a little to get it working. I found in the [documentation what appears to be a very simple example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types) of setting a `ctypes.c_char_p` object to point to a Python string.

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class cell(Structure):
...   pass
>>> cell._fields_ = [('name', c_char_p), ('next', POINTER(cell))]
>>> c1=cell()
>>> c1.name = "foo"
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```py
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

This error is consistent with what I would have expected based on what my code was running into. So, my question is, did I misunderstand the example or is this example not right?

Comment: Which python version are you using ? The example is for python 3.9, maybe it doesnt work with earlier versions

Comment: python version 3.8.6. Example is the same if you check 3.8 documentation.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour using Python3.6.9, but trying it on https://www.python.org/shell/ where the python version is 3.8.0 gives no error ...

Comment: But providing a bytes string as @ffdoctor suggested works on both versions

Comment: Thats bizarre. I'm getting an error with 3.8.6. It would be a pretty trivial fix to the docs to add the bytes modifier, but it also sounds like there might be something more subtle happening.

Comment: @Programmer the `python.org/shell` gives the same error.  Bytes strings are required for `c_char_p`.  The documentation example is in error.  Likely it was missed porting the documentation to Python 3.

Comment: bug submitted: https://bugs.python.org/issue43087

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are right, its giving an error in the online interpreter, but when i tried it yesterday it worked ...

Comment: It's good to know that the behaviour is consistent though.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the `ctypes.c_char_p` is a bytestream, not a string. If you write `c1.name = b'bar'` it should work. Then to recover a Python string from that you should decode it with `c1.name.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Yes, that's how to make it work, but the example shows something different. I just want to confirm the example is wrong or work out what I'm missing.

Comment: Mmm I tried on python.org/shell and I got the same error too, so I don't know. Could be a platform-dependent behaviour? According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24061473/12924454 it may make a difference.

Comment: @gph The example is wrong.  Byte strings (`b'xxxx'`) are required to initalize or be passed to `c_char_p`.